# About adding image in container in html language?

Tags: html

I want to enter a background image on which agriculture and the best agriculture will be showed.

```
<header class="w3-container w3-black w3-center" style="padding:128px 16px">
    <h1 class="w3-margin w3-jumbo">Agriculture</h1>
    <p class="w3-xlarge">The Best Agriculture</p>
</header>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by: *"...on which agriculture and the best agriculture will be showed"*?

Answer (score 0):

this save it on your html page

```
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("image_name_here.jpg");}
    </style>
```

or u can use like this

```
  <img src="image_name_here.jpg" height="420" width="420">
```

here is how your code would be

```
<header class="w3-container w3-black w3-center" style="padding:128px 16px">
    <h1 class="w3-margin w3-jumbo">Agriculture</br></br><img src="image_name_here.jpg" height="420" width="420"></h1>

    <p class="w3-xlarge">The Best Agriculture</br></br><style>
    .background {
        background-image: url("image_name_here.jpg");}
        </style>
</p><div class="background"></div>
</header>
```

just be sure the image is in the same folder of your html file and , replace image_name_here.jpg to the name of the image.jpg